# how to debug a mavenized Java and flex integrated code

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, spring, maven

I am trying to debug a flex code integrated with java as a backend. It is a mavenized project and I am using eclipse . I tried going through similar question like [How to debug Flex application under maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962114/how-to-debug-flex-application-under-maven) but I am not able to perform debugging properly. Can any one help me with this. I am not able to debug the code. The error which I am getting is very generic i.e. it just says problem in building the project and problem in executing the flex mojo. Can any one please help me with flex Debugging.

```
 Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-maven-plugin:3.9:compile-swf (default-compile-swf) on project succor-ui: Error compiling! -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-maven-plugin:3.9:compile-swf (default-compile-swf) on project succor-ui: Error compiling!
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:534)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error compiling!
    at org.sonatype.flexmojos.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.callCompiler(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1141)
    at org.sonatype.flexmojos.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.run(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:2404)
    at org.sonatype.flexmojos.AbstractIrvinMojo.execute(AbstractIrvinMojo.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
[ERROR]
```

Comment: please guide me and point me in right direction ..let me know what all set-up required to debug properly.... do we need Blazeds???

Comment: Where do you see the error?  Is it when launching a Flex Debug session from Flash Builder?  I think we'd need to know a lot more bout your environment to offer any value.

Comment: Basically, I am not even able to build the project. I am trying to add one Button to an already existing code.As soon as I comment my added code I am able to build the app only after I just add one normal button.. It fails... The problem is .. The stack trace doesn't shows where my code is failing .. It is rather showing the error in plug-in.. Please help

Comment: @www.Flextras.com please help me out . I am looking for proper setup since two days but not able to .

Comment: So, this is a compile time error.  Unfortunately, I don't think I can help more.  But, hopfully someone can see the stack trace and offer additional assistance.

Comment: But I feel my set-up is not proper because of which just on adding one button element, it throws compile time error. I am completely lost here. Can you atleast point me to some direction where I can find how to debug maven + flex + spring

Comment: @learner, you should try to use FlexMojos-4.0-RC1 and post your POM in your question.  I think the FlexMojos just hit a misconfiguration somewhere which caused the error.